# Leer fichero XML en Java

Tags: java, xml

Necesito primero listar todos los ficheros de una carpeta, coger el fichero o los ficheros que contengan la cadena 'MOD' en el título y modificar la etiqueta '' (formato: yyyy-MM-dd) con la fecha actual.
El XML es el siguiente:

```
<fichero>
<alta>
<usuario>x123</usuario>
<nombre>carlos</nombre>
<fecha>2020-07-04</fecha>
<edad>24</edad>
</alta>
</fichero>
```

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public class Fecha {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           
            String linea1 = null;
            String path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/prueba java/base/";
            BufferedReader comp1 = null;
            File filesBase = new File (path);
            File[] listaBase = filesBase.listFiles();
            
            for (int b = 0; b < listaBase.length; b++) {
                comp1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listaBase[b]));
                System.out.println(listaBase[b].getName());
                
                while ((linea1 = comp1.readLine()) != null){
                    
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            comp1.close();
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Estoy utilizando la API DOM pero en este caso no consigo encontrar el fichero para leerlo.

El código que estoy probando:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class AutomRegresionXml {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
            
            File file = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/prueba java/base/fichero.txt");
            
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            System.out.println(doc);
            
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("<Document>");
            System.out.println(nList.getLength());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }       
    }
}
```

El fichero XML que necesito modificar siempre contiene las siguientes lineas al principio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSPY v5 rel. 4 U (http://www.xmlspy.com) by CM (Commerce) -->
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.00X.XXX.XX" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.00X.XXX.XX
C:\Users\1237895\Desktop\XWSATA~1\pain.00X.XXX.XX.xsd">
```

Nose si es por eso por lo que no detecta las siguientes etiquetas.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema **específico**? Por favor, lee [ask].

Comment: El problema es que una vez leo el fichero, necesito coger esa etiqueta, modificarla por la fecha actual con el mismo formato y sobreescribir el mismo xml.

Answer (score 0):

las líneas que contiene el XML al principio como comentas, forman parte del encabezado del documento.

al utilizar la **API DOM** en la línea:
`NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("<Document>");` no es necesario que el tag sea declarado entre '<' y '>' y solo colocar el nombre del tag que deseas consutlar.

En todo caso, esa línea debería ser: `NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("fichero");`

Answer (score -1):

Te aconsejo que uses la **API DOM** de Java, es un modelo incorporado que trabaja muy bien con ficheros XML (tanto escritura como lectura). Te aconsejo que sigas algun tutorial, como por ejemplo este:
http://jmoral.es/blog/xml-dom

Los más conocidos en Java para manejar ficheros XMl son **DOM y SAX**, muy semejantes pero con diferencias en cuanto a optimización de memoria y manejo de datos (forma de árbol).

Comment: Un breve ejemplo de uso sería ideal para ayudar a que todo el mundo vea el funcionamiento de la librería aunque no la conozca :)

Comment: Por supuesto, de ahí a que haya insertado un enlace a UN TUTORIAL COMO BIEN HE NOMBRADO EN EL PROPIO COMENTARIO.

Comment: Y el día de mañana el tutorial deja de estar disponible porque el dueño de la página decide cerrarla y aquí se pierde toda referencia? [Los enlaces son volátiles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2883#2883). Y hazme un favor, deja de gritarme que yo no te estoy diciendo nada a malas, solamente intento que mejores tu respuesta para que pueda ayudar no solo al actual AP, si no a todos los que tengan la misma duda en el futuro.